# Let the trackball glow per code in Android java

Tags: java, android, mobile, trackball

How can I let the Trackball glow? I know my HTC Hero can do this, If I get a new SMS he is also glowing, so how do I program this? Nothing found for this...

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with [`android.app.Notification`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html). In particular by using the `FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS` flag and setting the `ledARGB`, `ledOffMS`, `ledOnMS` fields.

Note that not all devices support a notification LED and especially a very limited number of devices allows special colors for the notification (and last but not least, the LED is not always in the trackball).